# How much is a Sharepoint 2016 Server License?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, office-2016

I work for a technology solutions and consulting company and we just did a migration from Sharepoint Server 2010 to 2013, then to Sharepoint Server 2016. They have 60 licenses to office 365 essentials.

We are having trouble figuring out the software licensing costs for users because another company set up the hardware and is telling us it is $30 one time cost per user to have a SharePoint seat.  My customer has about 1500 people that need access to the SharePoint site, but only about 50 people with active directory e-mails that can log in.  When we try to share a page with someone who isn't in active directory, the site will not allow us to send them access.

I guess the main questions are what are the costs associated with licenses for SharePoint 2016 Server per user? and do we have to pay this licensing fee for people who aren't in active directory, but need to have read-only access to the SharePoint for policies and procedures?

Answer (score 1):

For pricing you have to contact the MSFT or the any partner. But

1. You need a license for each running instance of the SharePoint
2. You need a CAL for every person or device which access sharepoint.

Check this and may be contact via Chat to get price.[SharePoint 2016 licensing](https://products.office.com/en-us/SharePoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview)

There is one more thing, if you want to share the file with external user then

- In SharePoint 2016, for extranet and Internet sites scenarios, no
  CALs are required for external users. External users means users that
  are not either your or your affiliates’ employees, or your or your
  affiliates’ onsite contractors or onsite agents.

Comment: It's important to note that the OOTB Sharing functionality isn't the same as SPO, so you cannot just send a 'sharing invite'. Instead, your external users would need an Active Directory account, which requires a Windows User CAL (or Windows External Connector, depending on user count). The alternative would be to use some form of Forms-Based Authentication storage (LDAP or SQL), or a federation trust using SAML.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Waqas Sarwar post you can use [Microsoft License Advisor](http://mla.microsoft.com/) for high-level estimation of server license and CAL cost